# I am trying to write a simple Excel equation that will repeat a cell 60 times before switching to the cell in the next column and repeating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I'd like to use cell R1 "value A" right now to fill 60 rows from H242 to H301, then have the equation skip to S1 "value B" and fill the next 60 rows from H302 to H361. Then continue on with this 60 repeat, +1 column over, 60 repeat, etc.

Is there a way to do this using excel equations or programming in Excel?

Sorry if this is a bit noobie, I tried looking for an answer of the last 2 hours but couldn't find what I was looking for possibly because of my inability to search for the correct thing.

Comment: What, specifically, were you not able to find? You don't know how to write any formula in excel? You can't find the part that repeats a cell? Perhaps you can't find the part that switches to a new column? Try being more specific, and show what you HAVE done. If you haven't done anything at all, try starting with tutorials, you'll have better luck than asking questions on SO without demonstrating any effort.

Comment: Record a macro of doing it, and then use that source code to get you started. (You only have to record a macro of copying the cell once into the first column's 60 cells and then moving over one column, and then you can use that in a loop with a range of columns to repeat as needed.) Once you attempt to modify it and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem, *include the code you're having difficulty with*, and ask a specific question about that code. We're not really a tutorial site.

Comment: @leigero, there's no need to be a jerk. I did honestly search and look at youtube videos, but I'm not particularly well versed in programming. I didn't know how to switch to another column, but this is my first post, so forgive me for not mentioning every meticulous detail. I'm a scientist with a lot of work, so watching hours or days of tutorials to learn what I need isn't very practical, when I could simply ask someone here how it's done and then look into modifying it for future use.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you! The macro wasn't needed as the answer below was exactly what I needed, but I definitely will need to use the macro for more data cleaning later, I'll be sure to post my code if there's any problems I'm having. Thanks.

Comment: @EricVaughn Not being a jerk. The question is open ended and I'm trying to give you an idea of how it could/should be formatted so people will know how to better assit. Questions like this are often down-voted and abandoned.

Comment: @leigero "you'll have better luck than asking questions on SO without demonstrating any effort" kind of sounded like a jerk thing to me, but I am the noob, so maybe I'm just being sensitive. In any case, I'll be sure to include what I have done next time. Although, I must say that Gary's Student had no problem understanding what I was trying to figure out, so my question couldn't have been that flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a macro.

In **H242** enter:

```
=INDEX(R$1:ZZ$1,1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/60,0))
```

and copy down.

*NOTE:*

You may need to modify the *ZZ* if you need more data.

Comment: Fantastic! You just saved me hours of laboring! I'll definitely check out what these commands mean so I can manipulate them for future use.
Thank you so much!