# Program Excel loop to copy one column of values into 3 separate columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a murderously long data sheet with thousands of columns and rows that would take me days to edit, but I feel like there has to be a way to program what I want to do. I am a programming noob though, so sorry if this is simple (or impossible).

Right now I have 3 columns 'V' 'A' and 'D'. I have a list of participants with V A and D values. The problem is, the participant values are in one column, that is, I have 90 values in each column, for each participant. I need to break those 90 values into 30 'V', 30 'A', and 30 'D' values, and copied into their respective columns, and then switch to the next participant column and do the same.

Basically, I have:

```html
V    A    D       Participant 1  Participant 2  Participant 3  Etc.
                    1              1              1              1
                    2              2              2              2
                    3              4              3              5
                    4              6              9              0 
                    ...            ...            ...            ...
                    90             90             90             90
```

I need to break Participant 1's 90 values (place first 30 values in column V, next 30 in A, next 30 in D), then have Excel switch to Participant 2 break its 90 values into the V A and D columns. Then repeat this process.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: How do you know which value for each participant belongs to either `V`, `A` or `D`? Have you tried using a `pivot table` for this - no code required?

Comment: For each participant, the first 30 vertical values are V, the next 30 are A, the next 30 are D. Is that possible to break one column into 3 different columns with a Pivot Table? I have to do this process hundreds of times, so it would have to be easily automated or loopable.

Comment: A pivot table **could** get you there, but it would depend on how you wanted to use the output (and it would be easier if you had a column with the lables `v v v..., a a a...,...)`. As for code, have you written any `VBA`?

Comment: I performed a macro to get me started on the code in VBA, but don't know how to specify to Excel that I want the range to change each time the loop is performed. I really wish the data had been collected in a better fashion, but I've just joined a lab and am trying to sort some data behemoths for proper analysis. So I had no control over the original layout of the excel file.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Comment: And where do you want the output; each participant on a new worksheet, or all the participants on the same worksheet, but three columns for each participant?

Comment: I don't have the loop command in yet, but here's the basic macro code:
    `Range("N2:N31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("N32:N61").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("N62:N91").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: Never mind, I can't post a picture because I don't have the reputation points :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has two `for` loops, one for each participant (column) and one for each block of 30 values. It copies the first 30 values from the first participant and pastes it onto another worksheet. This is then repeated for the next block of 30, and the third block of 30. The outer loop then moves onto the next participant.

In this example I have three participants in columns `B`, `C` and `D` on worksheet "Sheet2", and the data values begin on row 2. The output gets pasted to "Sheet3", starting in column `F`

```
Sub transpose()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim outCol As Integer
    Dim outRow As Integer
    Dim intStart As Integer
    Dim intEnd As Integer
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim wksOut As Worksheet
    Dim strParticipant As String
    Dim strRange As String

    Set wksData = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wksOut = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    outRow = 2             'starting in row 2

    For i = 2 To 5          'columns of participants'

        strParticipant = wksData.Cells(1, i).Value
        outCol = 6              'output begins in column 6 ("F")

        For j = 1 To 3      'blocks of values per participant

            intStart = (j - 1) * 30 + 2 'increment for every block of 30 (starting at row 2)
            intEnd = intStart + 29

            wksData.Range(Cells(intStart, i), Cells(intEnd, i)).Copy
            wksOut.Cells(outRow, outCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

            outCol = outCol + 1

        Next j

        'The two lines below will output the participant's name - uncomment if required.
'            strRange = "E" & outRow & ":E" & outRow + 29
'            wksOut.Range(strRange) = strParticipant

        outRow = outRow + 30    'change the output row

    Next i

    Set wksData = Nothing
    Set wksOut = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Terrific! I've edited it to fit my data, the only problem I'm experiencing is that the output is in multiple V A D columns. I'd like to have only one V column, one A, and one D. How would I go about modifying this to put it all in the same row?
Other than that, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: You mean so that all the `V`s are in the same column, then all the `A`s are in the same column, etc?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. What would I change to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you also need to know which row corresponds to which participant?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem as I have already inserted an equation to paste the corresponding participant numbers. It should have all of participant 1's V, A, D, values first, then the next 30 below have participant 2's V, A, D, values, and so on.

Comment: Fantastic! You just saved me about a week of researching how to do this or the more painful route of copying and pasting this all in place! You're a hero!

Comment: no problem. Also, on SO you should 'tick' the accepted answer to let others know you've accepted a solution (this goes for your other question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412965/i-am-trying-to-write-a-simple-excel-equation-that-will-repeat-a-cell-60-times-be)